# Rsync files to server then run command on those files?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am using rsync -r to move some files from site A to site B. When they get to site B, I want to run some commands on them. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: The rsync utility is specifically for copying, managing, and comparing files in two different locations. It is a good choice for moving your files from site A to B. *Executing commands on files* is a entirely different activity, one that rsync has pretty much no primary concern with. I would suggest looking into creating a script that runs the rsync command(s) and then uses a method to run the commands on the remote system and manipulate the files. Rsync won't help you with this. Apples and oranges, screwdrivers and nails, etc.

Comment: Is there a better place to look into creating a script like that? I don't really know how to script.

Comment: I mostly need a way to find a list of synced files, with the path on site B. Then I can run anything.

Comment: Read the manual.  `rsync` can log the list of synced files to a file.

Comment: I've read the "log format" section of the rsyncd.conf man page, and the two filename options only give you the sender filename. Otherwise, the --out-format option would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

It you want to do it in a script, you can write something like this.

```
rsync -r A B
ssh B "<command1>; <command2>"
ssh B "<command3> && <command4>"
ssh B << EOF
<command5>
<command6>
EOF
```

Put your commands where `<commandX>` are written. In the example, you have three examples how to run multiple commands on the remote site.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync is built for moving files around. To execute scripts on a server the best option would be ssh.

You can ssh into another server and you then have a prompt just like you do on your home computer terminal from which you can execute arbitrary commands (assuming the programs needed are installed on the server). This process can be automated with scripts quite easily as long as you know SSH and the commands you need to execute.